# Что отвечать в опросе, если ни один из вариантов ответа не подходит?

Tags: обсуждение, stackoverflow, опрос

Который висит баннером. Честно продрался через все (несмотря на лютую "любовь" к этому делу), но на последнем вопросе завис. Это примерно как "перестали ли вы пить коньяк по утрам?"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну и что тут отвечать, если ни один из вариантов не подходит?

P.S. Особая эротика в том, что изначально никто не спрашивал ищу ли я работу :) И хотел ли вообще "обновлять резюме" (или я это пропустил на этапе EULA?)

Comment: Ну здесь видимо речь про резюме, в принципе, когда вы последний раз его обновляли.

Comment: @edem, опрос-то начинался с другого, посмотрите на баннер, который висит на ru::so :) Я честно начал отвечать на вопросы, продирался, даже думал... Кстати, спасибо, по предлагаемым вариантам было даже интересно что им интересно, в смысле языков и технологий :-)  А под конец такое. Это последний вопрос, на нём я страницу закрыл.

Comment: @PinkTux скажу по секрету - не обязателньо отвечать на все вопросы. можно просто ткнуть "Next" (или что там) не отвечая

Comment: @АлексейШиманский и получить потом знак серебряный ещё

Comment: @alexolut ...угу

Comment: Я всё собираюсь на метамете написать, в чём они в том опросе накосячили, это один из пунктов.

Answer (score 5):

> Ну и что тут отвечать, если ни один из вариантов не подходит?

Можно не отвечать на вопрос, если он вам не нравится, либо вы не знаете, что отвечать или не хотите отвечать (допустим, если не хотите давать ответ на вопросы, связанные с зарплатой).

Просто нажмите кнопку перехода к следующему вопросу.

Comment: Блин.. А так можно было? В смысле, на тех вопросах, на которых это не было предусмотрено?

Comment: @Qwertiy ну [так](http://i4.ytimg.com/vi/kdOPBP9vuZA/mqdefault.jpg)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский надо бы вас проверить на одинаковость с Grundy